# WinAPI: GetFontUnicodeRanges - I do not understand the result

Tags: delphi, unicode, fonts, range

I am trying to get Unicode font glyph ranges (Delphi 6):

```
var GS:PGlyphSet;
    GSSize:LongWord;
    rng:TWCRange;
begin
  GSSize := GetFontUnicodeRanges(Canvas.Handle, nil);
  GetMem(Pointer(GS), GSSize);
  try
    GS.cbThis:=GSSize;
    GS.flAccel:=0;
    GS.cGlyphsSupported:=0;
    GS.cRanges:=0;
    if GetFontUnicodeRanges(Canvas.Handle, GS)<>0 then begin
      for i:=0 to GS.cRanges-1 do begin
        rng := GS.ranges[i];
```

The strange thing is that `Length(GS.ranges)` is 1, but GS.cRanges is 309 and when I try to access the second range `GS.ranges[1]` I get, of course, a range check error. Before I turned range checking on it has worked in some magical way.

Types for reference (from `Windows` module):

```
PWCRange = ^TWCRange;
{$EXTERNALSYM tagWCRANGE}
tagWCRANGE = packed record
  wcLow: WCHAR;
  cGlyphs: SHORT;
end;
TWCRange = tagWCRANGE;

PGlyphSet = ^TGlyphSet;
{$EXTERNALSYM tagGLYPHSET}
tagGLYPHSET = packed record
  cbThis: DWORD;
  flAccel: DWORD;
  cGlyphsSupported: DWORD;
  cRanges: DWORD;
  ranges: array[0..0] of TWCRange;
end;
TGlyphSet = tagGLYPHSET;
```

Comment: If you want to avoid disabling the range check, declare `type
  TRangesArray = array[0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(TWCRange))-1] of TWCRange;
  PRangesArray = ^TRangesArray;` and use it like: `rng := PRangesArray(GS.ranges)^[i];`.

Comment: @LURD I borrowed that thought into my answer. By the way, your comment has minor error. Needs to be PRangesArray(@GS.ranges) of course.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, oops, was too fast there. I tend to use this construct rather than pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @LURD Personally I find that casting to pointer to large array technique rather ugly and tend to favour inc(p) in a loop. But it's personal, and for random access the pointer to large array cast is the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This struct makes use of the so-called struct hack:

- http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html
- http://tonywearme.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/c-struct-hack/

The `ranges` member is a variable length array, placed inline in the struct. But you cannot actually encode that in a static C type. That's why you call the function to find out how much memory to allocate, and then heap allocate the struct. If you allocated it on the stack, or using `SizeOf(...)` then the struct would be too small.

The simplest thing to do is to disable range checking for the code that accesses `ranges`. Although the type declaration says that only `0` is a valid index for `ranges`, in fact `0..cRanges-1` are valid.

If you don't want to disable range checking for the relevant code, then take a pointer the element 0, and then use pointer arithmetic in your loop.

```
var
  rng: PWCRange; 
....
rng := @GS.ranges[0];
for i:=0 to GS.cRanges-1 do begin
  // use rng^
  inc(rng);
end;
```

This is, in my view, the cleanest way to write code for sequential access. For random access, and with range checking in force, you'd be compelled to declare some extra types to defeat range checking:

```
type 
  TWCRangeArray = array [0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(TWCRange))-1] of TWCRange; 
  PWCRangeArray = ^TWCRangeArray;
```

And then use type casting to access individual elements:

```
rng := PWCRangeArray(@GS.ranges)[i];
```